# On Windows, running "import tensorflow" generates No module named "_pywrap_tensorflow" error

Tags: tensorflow

On Windows, TensorFlow reports either or both of the following errors after executing an `import tensorflow` statement:

- `No module named "_pywrap_tensorflow"`
- `DLL load failed.`

Answer (score 79):

The problem was the cuDNN Library for me - for whatever reason cudnn-8.0-windows10-x64-v6.0 was NOT working - I used cudnn-8.0-windows10-x64-v5.1 - ALL GOOD!

My setup working with Win10 64 and the Nvidia GTX780M:

- Be sure you have the lib MSVCP140.DLL by checking your system/path - if not get it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)
- Run the windows installer for python 3.5.3-amd64 from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-352/) - DO NOT try newer versions as they probably won't work
- Get the cuDNN v5.1 for CUDA 8.0 from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download) - put it under your users folder or in another known location (you will need this in your path)
- Get CUDA 8.0 x86_64 from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)
- Set PATH vars as expected to point at the cuDNN libs and python (the python path should be added during the python install)
- Make sure that ".DLL" is included in your PATHEXT variable
- If you are using tensorflow 1.3 then you want to use cudnn64_6.dll [github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7705](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7705)

If you run Windows 32 be sure to get the 32 bit versions of the files mentioned above.

Comment: It may be obvious to most but the CUDA DLL is 'cudnn64_5.dll' and the folder it is in needs to be in the path.. not the parent folder. I dropped it in '%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\cuda\bin;'

Comment: After you add to the PATH remember to close your command prompt and open it again.  Also, it's worth typing "cudnn64_5.dll" into your command prompt to make sure you got the path settings right.

Comment: Thank you for saving my time.

Comment: I just spent 4 hours debugging this, if you are using tensorflow 1.3 then you want to use cudnn64_6.dll https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7705

Comment: Also just spent hours on this. If you use tensorflow 1.3 you will have to download cuDNN v6.0 even though Tensorflow's instructions specifically say you have to use 5.1

Comment: Chris Barret's comment solved it - if you are installing after Aug 2017 chances are you'll need cuDNN v6,0 not 5 or 7.

Comment: In my case, python 3.5.4 also worked. And I wasn't able to install cuda 8.0 until remove vs17 and install visual studio 15(win10). It's really ridiculous that I had to find and install old versions one by one.

Comment: Thanks for the help, here is my working setup as of November 1st, 2017:
- Windows 10 Pro x64
- MS Visual Studio Community 2017 15.4.2, for MSVC++2015 redist., any >14.0 is ok
- python 3.6.3, from chocolatey
- tensorflow-gpu 1.3.0, from pip, use it w/out CPU pkg or install GPU 2nd
- CUDA 8.0, from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive
- cuDNN 6.0, from https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download, copy files to CUDA directories

Reinstalling CUDA 8.0 *without newer versions installed* was key for me.

FYI tensorflow (1.3) dependency versions might change in the future

Comment: Had the same problem, nothing fixed it. Resorted to installing Anaconda (which i dont like) but it is working through the Spider app found in the Anaconda Navigator program. Hope this helps.

Comment: Perhaps this is obvious, but I assume you do not install cuDNN if you are not running with a GPU.

Comment: I resolved the same issue thanks to this tuto https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRaRi6f5Qcs (installing tensorflow for sse)

Comment: ? as I understood:  first & foremost graphics cards (or videocard) should support CUDA, if not - then neither of advised ways will help. Anyway thank you for your recommendations - am still having this error

Answer (score 22):

In my case the "cudnn64_6.dll" file in the /bin folder had to be renamed to "cudnn64_5.dll" for the error to go away. I easily spent two hours to figure this out, and I followed the official install guide to the letter. This is true for installation via pip (officially supported) and conda (community supported).

Comment: This was my case. TensorFlow requires "cuDNN v5.1" but if you install cuDNN v6.0, then the file name of the cudnn dll file will be `cudnn64_6.dll` not `cudnn64_5.dll`.

Comment: If you are using tensorflow 1.3 then you want to use cudnn64_6.dll https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7705

Comment: I am using tensorflow 1.3 and I had to change from cudnn64_7.dll (newest version right now) to cudnn64_6.dll as @ChrisBarrett says to make it work.

Comment: In case of tensorflow 1.3 and cudNN 7, similarly renaming `cudnn64_7.dll` to `cudnn64_6.dll` helps.

Answer (score 13):

Either error indicates that your system has not installed `MSVCP140.DLL`,
which TensorFlow requires.

To fix this error:

1. Determine whether `MSVCP140.DLL` is in your `%PATH%` variable.
2. If `MSVCP140.DLL` is not in your `%PATH%`, install the 
    [Visual C++ 2015 redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) (x64 version), which contains this DLL.

Comment: This may or may not fix his issue (depending on CPU vs GPU) and although the windows dll is needed it could be another issue as well - see answer below. I had no issues with the windows dll but instead had an issue with cuDNN v6.0

Comment: You can checked if MSVCP140.dll is in your path by typing the following at the command prompt: where MSVCP140.DLL

Comment: The link takes you to the 2010 version.  Are we aiming for the 2015 or 2010 version?

Comment: [In my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64944065/tensorflow-importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-pywrap-tensorflow-inter#69874313) (TF 2.5.0) a different DLL `vcruntime140_1.dll` was missing - but thanks to your answer, it gave me a clue where to look!

Answer (score 12):

I have Win7 Pro 64-bit on AMD cpu, no gpu. I was following the instructions under "Installing with native pip" at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows. The installation step went ok but the attempt to import tensorflow produced the infamous:

```
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
```

This seems to be one of those situations where a lot of unrelated things can go wrong, depending on configuration, which all cascade through to the same error.

In my case, installing MSVCP140.DLL was the answer.

You have `MSVCP140.DLL` already if

1. you have a file `C:\Windows\System32\MSVCP140.DLL`, AND
2. if you have a 64 bit system, then you additionally have `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSVCP140.DLL`.

I installed it manually, which was unnecessary (the redistributable is not the whole Visual C++ development mess and isn't large). Use the link posted earlier in this thread to install it: [Visual C++ 2015 redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555http://).

Also, I recommend that you override the default install directory for Python and put it anywhere not under `C:\Program Files`, because Windows tries to write-protect files there, which causes problems later.

Answer (score 11):

**For tensorflow with CPU only:**

---

I had installed tensorflow using command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

This installed `tensorflow 1.7` 

But could not import the tensorflow from withing `python 3.6.5 amd64` using:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

So, i downgraded the tensorflow version from `1.7` to `1.5` using following command:

```
pip3 install tensorflow==1.5
```

This uninstalled the previous version and installed `1.5`. Now it works.

Seems that, my [CPU does not support AVX instruction](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17807) set that is needed in `tensorflow 1.7`

I had `MSVCP140.DLL` in the system folders and .DLL in the PATHEXT variable in Environment Variable.

Comment: my system: Windows 8.1, Python 3.6.5 64 Bit, No GPU.

Comment: Might have to be updated, as since version 2.0.0, tensorflow-gpu is integrated into the regular installation - see here: https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel

Maybe you want to consider my answer here where the compatibility between different versions of python and tensorflow is explained: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45749992/how-to-downgrade-tensorflow-multiple-versions-possible/62855139#62855139

Answer (score 8):

`TensorFlow` requires `MSVCP140.DLL`, which may not be installed on your system.
To solve it open the terminal en type or paste this link:

```
C:\> pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

**Note this is to install the CPU-only version of TensorFlow.**

Comment: For my configuration, the binary that worked was: https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.4.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl -- Check https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow for available built binaries. I checked for a couple of them until the "import tensorflow as tf" succeed.

Answer (score 8):

cuDNN causes my problem. PATH variable doesn't work for me. I have to copy the files in my cuDNN folders into respectful CUDA 8.0 folder structure.

Answer (score 6):

For Those Running on Older Hardware:

You may get this same error due to having an older CPU using tensorflow-gpu 1.6.

If your cpu was made before 2011, then your max tensorflow-gpu version is 1.5.

Tensorflow 1.6 requires AVX instructions on your cpu.  Verified here: [Tensorflow Github docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/RELEASE.md)

AVX enabled CPUs:  [Wiki AVX CPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions#CPUs_with_AVX)

What I did in my conda environment for tensorflow:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==1.5
```

Answer (score 5):

I posted a general approach for troubleshooting the "DLL load failed" problem in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51606222/10157759) on Windows systems. For reference:

> 1. Use the DLL dependency analyzer [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) to analyze `<Your Python Dir>\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd` and determine the exact missing DLL (indicated by a `?` beside the
>    DLL). The path of the .pyd file is based on the TensorFlow 1.9 GPU
>    version that I installed. I am  not sure if the name and path is the
>    same in other TensorFlow versions.
> 2. Look for information of the missing DLL and install the appropriate package to resolve the problem.

Comment: I like this approach since it explicitly shows which dlls are missing. Found out that tensorflow 1.11 is looking for CUDA 9 dlls and seems not to search for CUDA 10 libraries.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion! On my machine the problem was that tensorflow was looking for DLL's that come with CUDA tookit v9, but I installed CUDA toolkit v10

Comment: This is incredibly useful. Notice that you have to select `All files (*.*)` next to file name instead of just `exe files (*.exe, *.dll)`.

Comment: Excellent tip! [In my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64944065/tensorflow-importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-pywrap-tensorflow-inter#69874313) I found my TF 2.5.0 install was requesting an additional `vcruntime140_1.dll` beyond what is usually documented online

Answer (score 4):

The problem for me was the cuDNN library which didn't match the requirements of the graphics card. I downloaded the 6.0 version but for my GTX980ti but the recommended compute capability on the nvidia website was 5.1 ( http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus ) so I downloaded 5.1 and replaced the 6.0 version and as soon as I've done that it started working.

Answer (score 4):

After much trial and error, and making sure *VC++ 2015 Redistributable*, *cuDNN* DLL and all other dependencies are accessible from PATH, it looks like *Tensorflow GPU* works only with Python `3.5.2` (as of this writing)

So if you're using `Anaconda`

- `conda create -n tensorflow-gpu python=3.5.2`
- `activate tensorflow-gpu`
- `pip install tensorflow-gpu`

Then open the python interpreter and verify

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

> Found device 0 with properties:
>   name: GeForce 940M
>   major: 5 minor: 0
>   memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.176
>   pciBusID 0000:06:00.0
>   Total memory: 2.00GiB
>   Free memory: 1.66GiB

Credits: [this neat guide](https://nitishmutha.github.io/tensorflow/2017/01/22/TensorFlow-with-gpu-for-windows.html)

Answer (score 4):

For each Tensorflow's version, it requires different version of CuDnn. On [www.tensorflow.org](http://www.tensorflow.org), they did not mentioned about that in installation guide!

My case use tensorflow version 1.3 which uses cuDNN 6. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases.

Please check your tensorfow version and cuDNN version if they are match together.

And please set path environment for cuDNN, if it still does not work, please check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43632183/4575793) from @[Chris Han](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4679530/chris-han).

Answer (score 2):

One may be tempted to keep the Powershell/cmd open on Windows. I've spent reasonable time till I decided to close and reopen my Powershell only to realize that I've done everything right.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are trying to install tensorflow GPU in Windows, you can find [this](https://nitishmutha.github.io/tensorflow/2017/01/22/TensorFlow-with-gpu-for-windows.html) easy interesting tutorial.

Note: If you are using PyCharm for example, you have to change the interpreter to the created conda environment.

Answer (score 2):

For the people finding this post in 2019, this error could also occur because the Python version 3.7 does not have support for TensorFlow (see https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip). So, check the Python version:

```
python --version
```

In case it is larger than 3.6, it should be downgraded to 3.6. For Anaconda:

```
conda install python=3.6
```

Then, install TensorFlow.

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Btw, I did not have the GPU version, so there were no CUDA related issues in my case.

Comment: I did that I still have to same problem

Comment: This worked for me on two different computers used by my students. We still had the problem after trying the solutions above. In your case, it might be a situation described above.

Answer (score 1):

Dll not found. Install Visual C++ 2015 redistributable to fix.

Comment: Not sure this covers it exactly - depending on scenario - see above answer related to cuDNN v6.0 - also may want to include the link to the lib you mention (which i will do right here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145 vs this quick blurb :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the cuDNN Library for me. I was able to run [the test code](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) after adding the directory (possibly bin folder) of the cuDNN DLL (not LIB file) in the Windows PATH.

For the reference, I installed TensorFlow from the source using PIP and my OS: Windows 7 and IDE: Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1):

With TensorFlow release 1.3.0, you need to use Cudnn 6.0 instead of Cudnn 5.0 as Cudnn 5.0 is giving this error. Don't forget to add path variable to Cudnn 6.0 .With cudnn64_6.dll your Tensorflow will work fine. Read the link below.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/RELEASE.md#release-130

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

I had a ton of problems trying to get my CUDA 8.0 installed properly on Windows 7. I had a previous version installed and I wanted to upgrade so I uninstalled it and tried to install CUDA 8.0 (for tensorflow 1.3). The installation failed every single time, I tried to downgrade to CUDA 7.5 and was able to install it but had a ton of problems with tensorflow (similar to the PATH problem described here). Long story short: what worked for me was:

1) Uninstall EVERY NVIDIA component (except the display graphics driver)

2) Download CUDA toolkit 8.0 (and the patch) https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

3) Check the CheckSum MD5 (I used MS https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/confirmation.aspx?id=11533 but any would do) to make sure they were OK (it happened several times that the installer was not dowloaded properly because my WiFi router apparently).

4) Run the CUDA toolkit installer as root

5) download the cudnn 8.0 v6 and add its location to the PATH variable https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download

Hope that helps and saves some headaches...

NOTE: This script helped me a lot to debug the problem! (Thank you mrry)
https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c

Answer (score 1):

I will try to give the solution that worked for me. It seems that different set of problems can lead to this situation.

32 bit software works in 64 bit OS. I installed anaconda-3 (32 bit) in my 64 bit OS. It was working perfectly fine. I decided to install tensorflow in my machine and it wouldn't install at first. I was using conda environment to install tensorflow and got this error.

Solution is **if you are running 64 bit OS, install 64 bit anaconda and if 32 bit OS then 32 bit anaconda**. Then follow the standard procedure mentioned in tensorflow website for windows (anaconda installation). This made it possible to install tensorflow without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

my answer is for windows 10 users only  as I have tried the following on windows 10.
Extending some of the answers above I suggest this : 
If you are using anaconda then you can avoid everything and simply install **anaconda-navigator** using the command

```
conda install -c anaconda anaconda-navigator
```

Then you can launch the navigator from command prompt  using the command

```
anaconda-navigator
```

On running this command you get a simple gui where you can create an virtual environment, create the environment with python=3.5.2 and install module tensorflow-gpu or tensorflow by searching the module in the search box using gui, it will also take care of installing correct cuda files for you. Using anaconda navigator is the simplest solution.

If you are not using anaconda then take care about the following

tensorflow-gpu 1.3 requires python 3.5.2, cuda development kit 8.0 and cudaDNN 6.0, hence when installing make sure you run the command

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.3
```

tensorflow-gpu 1.2.1 or less requires python 3.5.2, cuda development kit 8.0 and cudaDNN 5.1 hence when installing make sure you run the command

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.2.1
```

Below are the steps you need to follow for both of the above processes
Setting up you path variables
You must have the following system variables

```
CUDA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0"
CUDA_PATH = "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0"
CUDA_PATH_V8.0 = "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0"
```

You PATHTEXT must include ".DLL" along with other extensions

```
".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.DLL"
```

Also Add the following to you path

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib\x64
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\extras\CUPTI\libx64;
C:\Windows\SysWOW64;
C:\Windows\System32
```

If you are getting errors you can download the run the below code by mrry, this code will check your setup and tell you if something is wrong
https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c

References : 
http://blog.nitishmutha.com/tensorflow/2017/01/22/TensorFlow-with-gpu-for-windows.html

The above reference is very useful.
Please comment for improvements to this answer.
Hope this helps, Thanks.

Comment: The anaconda option sounds great, but looking at https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu the tensorflow-gpu version for windows seems to be 1.1, any way to get the 1.3 through anaconda?

Comment: @ftiaronsem There is no way to install 1.3 using the anaconda-navigator if you want 1.3 then follow the reference link and make a note to use cudaDNN 6.0

Answer (score 1):

tensorflow 1.3 does not support **cuda 9.0** yet.
I degrade to **cuda 8.0**, then it works.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem (**in *20190909***) while investigating [[SO]: Error while training using the estimator API in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57588589/4788546).

Setup:

- *Win 10 pc064*
- *Python 3.7.3* (*pc064*)
- *TensorFlow-**GPU** 1.13.1* ([[TensorFlow]: Install TensorFlow with pip](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip))

**Error**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057588589]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import tensorflow as tf"
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
>     from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
>     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>     _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>     return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>     return _load(spec)
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
>     from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
>     from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
>     raise ImportError(msg)
> ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
>     from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
>     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>     _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>     return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>     return _load(spec)
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
> above this error message when asking for help.
> ```

Looking at the "faulty" module (thanks to [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com)), it turns out that **it's not itself that's missing, but some of its dependencies** (the *cu*_**100**.dll* files).

[image: Img0]

Check [[SO]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546) (the **Conclusions** section at the end, and (referenced) [[SO]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74883130/4788546)) for more details on this kind of errors.
I had an older *CUDA Toolkit* version (***8***), and as a consequence, the *cu*_**80**.dll* files.

Upgrading to *TensorFlow-GPU 1.**14**.0* (`"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu`), made the error a bit clearer (and also shorter):

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057588589]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import tensorflow as tf"
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 75, in preload_check
>     ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.cudart_dll_name)
>   File "c:\install\x64\python\python\03.07.03\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
>     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
> OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
>     from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
>     from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
>     self_check.preload_check()
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 82, in preload_check
>     % (build_info.cudart_dll_name, build_info.cuda_version_number))
> ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_100.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 10.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive
> ```

**Steps**:

- Uninstall any *CUDA Toolkit* version (optional)
- Install [[nVidia.Developer]: CUDA Toolkit 10.0 Archive](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.0-download-archive)

  - **Make sure to install *v10.0*** (that **this *TensorFlow-GPU* version was built against - check [[TensorFlow]: Build from source on Windows - GPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu)**). I installed *v10.**1*** (which was the latest, and also the recommended version at the answer time), and the *.dll* names didn't match (*cu*_10**1**.dll*). Since I didn't want to install *v10.0*, I created some *symlink*s (with the "correct" names) to the existing files, and it worked. But **bear in mind that this is unsupported!!! You may experience funny behavior (including crashes)**. This is a (lame) workaround (*gainarie*)
  - Additionally, a **compatible** (meaning that it's for a specific *CUDA Toolkit* version) *cuDNN* version ([[nVidia.Developer]: cuDNN Archive](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive)) is required. In order to access the download *URL*, *nVidia* membership is required

After the above steps, and also setting the correct paths, it worked:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057588589]> set PATH=%PATH%;%CUDA_PATH%\bin;f:\Install\x64\NVidia\GPU Computing Toolkit\cuDNN\7.6\bin
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057588589]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import tensorflow;print(\"Success!!!\")"
> Success!!!
> ```