# Tensor flow cannot be imported properly in windows 8.1 64 bit Laptop

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed CPU version of Tensor flow in my laptop using the command line using pip install.

OS: Windows 8.1
64 bit
Python 3.5.1

But, when I tried importing it in the python 3.5.1 it throws the following error message.

> import _pywrap_tensorflow ImportError: No module named
>   '_pywrap_tensorflow' Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using
>   bazel, you should not try to import tensorflow from its source
>   directory; please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your
>   python interpreter from there.

I have tried getting answers in Github, but no hope. I have even tried changing the directories but nothing works.

I am new to python. Please help me to solve this issue !!

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5949), it may be caused by you not having [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 (x64 version)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587). Can you verify that that's not your problem?

Comment: I think it is not the problem !!

Comment: Which Python distribution are you using? From Python.org, Anaconda or other?

Comment: Have you done your due diligence per this Stack Overflow question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso

Comment: I am using Python.org distribution. I have even tried due diligence as per the link already. But it is still not working !!