# Tensorflow GPU installation Error Windows 10 Anaconda

Tags: download, tensorflow, installation, runtime-error, gpu

I am having a tough time trying to setup Tensorflow for GPU use. I am no Windows 10, have already downloaded CUDA® Toolkit 8.0, cuDNN v5.1. and uninstalled Visual C++ 2015 redistributable and reinstalled as suggested by [On Windows, running "import tensorflow" generates No module named "_pywrap_tensorflow" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso) but this did not have any effect. I am also not really sure about the PATH or if everything is included correctly there. Here is the error I keep getting (sorry it is not properly quoted but I kept getting formatting errors):

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393] (c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation.
>   All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\Austin>activate test_env
>
> (test_env) C:\Users\Austin>python
>
> Python 3.5.3 | packaged by
>   conda-forge | (default, Feb  9 2017, 15:12:38) [MSC v.1900 64 bit
>   (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for
>   more information.
>
> >>> import tensorflow as tf
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 18, in swig_import_helper return importlib.import_module(mname)
>   File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126,
>   in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package,
>   level) File "", line 986, in _gcd_import
>   File "", line 969, in _find_and_load File
>   "", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>   File "", line 666, in _load_unlocked File
>   "", line 577, in module_from_spec File
>   "", line 914, in create_module
>   File "", line 222, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 41, in  from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal
>   import * File
>   "C:\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 21, in 
>   _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 20, in swig_import_helper return
>   importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal') File
>   "C:\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in
>   import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package,
>   level) ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in 
>   File
>   "C:\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py",
>   line 24, in  from tensorflow.python import * File
>   "C:\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py",
>   line 51, in  from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>   File
>   "C:\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 52, in  raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback
>   (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 18, in swig_import_helper return importlib.import_module(mname)
>   File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126,
>   in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package,
>   level) File "", line 986, in _gcd_import
>   File "", line 969, in _find_and_load File
>   "", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>   File "", line 666, in _load_unlocked File
>   "", line 577, in module_from_spec File
>   "", line 914, in create_module
>   File "", line 222, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 41, in  from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal
>   import * File
>   "C:\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 21, in 
>   _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 20, in swig_import_helper return
>   importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal') File
>   "C:\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in
>   import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package,
>   level) ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See
>   https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.
>
> >>>

---

And here is what I get for my PATH (I think this is the problem, but I really don't know enough about what the PATH even is...)

> (test_env) C:\Users\Austin>PATH
>   PATH=C:\Anaconda3\envs\test_env;C:\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\Library\usr\bin;C:\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\Library\bin;C:\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\Scripts;C:\Program
>   Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\libnvvp;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Tesseract-OCR;C:\Anaconda3;C:\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Program
>   Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
>   Toolkit\cudnn-8.0-windows10-x64-v5.1\cuda;C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\microsoft
>   shared\ClickToRun;C:\Users\Austin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Austin\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
>
> (test_env) C:\Users\Austin>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. Needed to copy the contents of the  downloaded cudnn into the respective locations inside the CUDA folder (i.e. lib, bin, etc.)