# import tensorflow gpu enabled error

Tags: tensorflow

Python version is 3.5.2 (64it). OS: windows 10. vs2015 redistributed x64 installed. And my path variable is:
[enter image description here][1]

Got the error when I import tensorflow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On Windows, running "import tensorflow" generates No module named "\_pywrap\_tensorflow" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso)