# Error with importing tflearn and more

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tflearn

I am following a simple tutorial, from [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/openai-cartpole-neural-network-example-machine-learning-tutorial/), about some deep learning in neural networks and while testing my code, I ran into an issue with several exceptions, seen here (first my code, then the tracebacks):

```
import gym
import random
import numpy as np
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
from statistics import mean, median
from collections import Counter

LR = 1e-3
env = gym.make("CartPole-v0")
env.reset()
goal_steps = 500
score_requirment = 50
initial_games = 10000

def some_random_games_first():
    for episode in range(5):
        env.reset()
        for t in range(goal_steps):
            env.render()
            action = env.action_space.sample()
            observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
            if done :
                break

some_random_games_first()
```

When I then run this code I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
  return importlib.import_module(mname)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 914, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jeppe/OneDrive/Dokumenter/Python Scripts/Neural Network/Open AI Cartpole example/openaiexample.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tflearn
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tflearn\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import config
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 914, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

These are my specs:

- Windows 10, with what I believe to be the latest update
- Python v 3.5.3
- TensorFlow (gpu version) v 1.1.0
- ProtoBuff v 3.2.0
- Numpy v 1.12.1
- WerkZeug v 0.11.10
- TFLearn v 0.3

Everything is freshly installed, after some issues with installing TensorFLow. I can't decipher the tracebacks myself, therefore I am hoping some of you guys can help me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. CUDNN might be one of the reasons. cuDNN v6.0 does not work for many people. Try with cuDNN v5.1.
2. Importing from inside GIT folder is also one of the reasons.

You can read more here : [On Windows, running "import tensorflow" generates No module named "_pywrap_tensorflow" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I checked the link, didnt work, but I don't know what you mean with your two other points

Comment: [1] Are you using CUDNN ? [2] Are you running this code inside Git folder of Tensorflow ?

Comment: Yes I am using cuDNN and it is version 5.1 and no I am not running this code inside the git folder for TensorFlow

Comment: I see. Most of the other cases are answered in above link. Are you sure DLL is installed and in the right path ?

Comment: I don't really know... I have the dll and it is located in C:\Windows\system32 but I don't know if this is the correct location

Comment: what is the name of your DLL ? is it cudnn64_5.dll ? Could you drop it in  '%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\cuda\bin;' and run again ?

Comment: It is called msvcp140.dll and I don't have a folder in the location you mentioned

Comment: Do you have CUDA installed ?

Comment: Yes - again I have followed the guide linked in the post and had to install TensorFlow, therefore also Cuda

Comment: where is CUDA installed ? Path of the CUDA library ?

Comment: The Cuda library is located in Program Files

Comment: may be try copying dll file to cuda\bin location and run it ?

Comment: I am not sure what did it, but I have just restarted my pc and now it works, so I hope it was merely just a small hickup after I had made a bunch of changes, anyhow thank you @hars