# import tensorflow generates error for tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I've installed all the necessary GPU drives / cudNN etc. and made all the configurations necessary by following the instructions from the [official Tensorflow page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows), but when trying to import tensorflow I get the following error trace.

I do want to mention that I have looked at the common problems section at the bottom of the official TF install page, which says that I should install / reinstall Visual C++ 2015 redistributable (x64 version), and I made sure it's part of `PATH` system environment variable, but still I get errors.

By the way, **I'm using Python 3.5.3**.

```
`import tensorflow as tf`

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\radu.gheorghiu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)   File "C:\Users\radu.gheorghiu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in
_call_with_frames_removed ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\radu.gheorghiu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Users\radu.gheorghiu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Users\radu.gheorghiu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')   File "C:\Users\radu.gheorghiu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "C:\Users\radu.gheorghiu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *   File "C:\Users\radu.gheorghiu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "C:\Users\radu.gheorghiu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\radu.gheorghiu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)   File "C:\Users\radu.gheorghiu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in
_call_with_frames_removed ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\radu.gheorghiu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Users\radu.gheorghiu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Users\radu.gheorghiu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')   File "C:\Users\radu.gheorghiu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace above this error message when asking for help.
```

If I try and install Tensorflow for CPU it works without any problems.

---

**Update:**

I've checked my `%PATH%` environment variable and the files are specified:

```
(C:\Users\radu.gheorghiu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tflow) C:\Users\radu.gheorghiu\AnacondaProjects>echo %path%
...
F:\gpuDrivers\cuda\bin\cudnn64_6.dll;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\msvcp140.dll
```

Maybe am I not referencing to the correct `msvcp140.dll`?

Comment: Did you look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @hars Thanks, but I have had a look here and mentioned that in my question, although possibly it wasn't very clear.

Comment: Are the CUDA and cuDNN DLLs also in directories that are in your `%PATH%` (I believe they still get installed to different directories by default)?

Comment: @mrry I've installed the latest drivers for my video card (GT 730M - it has a compute score of 3.0, the minimum required) and I've placed the cuDNN DLL's in a folder and made SURE that the folder they are in is included in `%PATH%`. Actually the cuDNN DLLs are just in a .zip archive, no installation required. The only installation I've made was for `Visual C++ 2015 redistributable`, whose `MSVCP140.DLL` I've specified with full path in my `%PATH%` variable as well. I will re-check tomorrow when I get back into work, even though I've done this a couple of times so far, starting from scratch.

Comment: @mrry I've rechecked my setup and it looks about right. Can you please have a look at the updates in my question?