# TensorFlow importerror on windows cmd

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have installed python 3.5.2, and installed TensorFlow throght the command 
pip3 install tensorflow --upgrade
After the installation finished, I try to import the TensorFlow, but failed. The error report is as follow. How to fix this problem?

> > > > import tensorflow Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
> > > >         line 18, in swig_import_helper
> > > >             return importlib.import_module(mname)   File "C:\Python\Python352\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in
> > > >         import_module
> > > >             return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 986, in _gcd_import   File
> > > >         "", line 969, in _find_and_load   File
> > > >         "", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
> > > >         File "", line 666, in _load_unlocked
> > > >         File "", line 577, in module_from_spec
> > > >         File "", line 906, in
> > > >         create_module   File "", line 222, in
> > > >         _call_with_frames_removed ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。(Could not find the moudle)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 41, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Python\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 21, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Python\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 20, in swig_import_helper
>       return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')   File "C:\Python\Python352\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in
>   import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "C:\Python\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line
>   24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import *   File "C:\Python\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py",
>   line 51, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "C:\Python\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 52, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflo
>   w_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
>       return importlib.import_module(mname)   File "C:\Python\Python352\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in
>   import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 986, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 969, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 666, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 577, in module_from_spec
>   File "", line 906, in
>   create_module   File "", line 222, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。(could not find the moudle)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflo
>   w.py", line 41, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Python\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 21, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Python\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 20, in swig_import_helper
>       return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')   File "C:\Python\Python352\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in
>   import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso

Comment: @JCooke It does work! Thank you very much!