# Error Installing TensorFlow on Windows

Tags: tensorflow

Followed the instructions and installed Python 3.5.2 as listed at:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

To validate the installation I typed:

import tensorflow as tf

and got the following load of crap:

```
C:\>python
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\O2 user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_help
er
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\O2 user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__
init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\O2 user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\O2 user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\O2 user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_help
er
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\O2 user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__
init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\O2 user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\O2 user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\O2 user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\O2 user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_help
er
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\O2 user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__
init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\O2 user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\O2 user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\O2 user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_help
er
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\O2 user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__
init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_probl
ems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
>>>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On Windows, running "import tensorflow" generates No module named "\_pywrap\_tensorflow" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso)

Comment: Appears downloading "cuDNN v5.1 for CUDA 8.0 from here" is not that straightforward since NVidia require either a university or corporate account, an application can take upto 72hours and may be declined! What if you're not a university or corporate person - how to get the driver?

Comment: Why do I even need the CUDA stuff when I used "C:\> pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow" as stated on the installation page, which is the non-gpu version?

Comment: You say read the stacktrace. What would "_pywrap_tensorflow" mean to a new windows tensorflow user?

Comment: At the end of the stack trace is a url to follow that gives you links to solutions for common errors. --> https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_probl
ems - Here you will see that the 2 errors you encountered are covered here along with on-going support links. Regarding CUDA, you are correct in that if you are only using the CPU version then you don't need the CUDA parts. Anyone can download them. I got them straight away after filling out the form.

Comment: What happened when you tried the solution: "Be sure you have the lib MSVCP140.DLL by checking your system/path"?