# Unable to import tensorflow python in Windows 7

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed python 3.6 and tensorflow successfully from this command:

```
C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36:\>pip tensorflow install
```

Now I am trying to check the installation but it's giving me this error:

```
C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\tenso
rflow>python
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
 on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper

    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__in
it__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 648, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper

    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__in
it__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper

    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__in
it__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 648, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper

    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__in
it__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_probl
ems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I have tried some solution that I have found like change the directory etc. but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem with installing Tensorflow. These errors can usually be resolved on windows by following the instructions from this answer here: [On Windows, running "import tensorflow" generates No module named "_pywrap_tensorflow" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/)

You can use @mrry's installation checker for Windows here to assist with troubleshooting your problem:

https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c

The first step is usually to check that MSVCP140.DLL is installed. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for reply,I have this dll in C:\Windows\SysWOW64.The link above you mentioned have multiple anwser which one should I folow?

Comment: I am using CPU version of tensor flow

Comment: Have a go at all the troubleshooting steps apart from ones that relate to the GPU. Also have a go at running the script by mrry