# Tensorflow-gpu on windows: ImportError: No module named _pywrap_tensorflow

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, anaconda

When I try to `import tensorflow` I get the following error:

```
>>import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow')
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named _pywrap_tensorflow


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I installed the `msvcp140.dll Redistributable` as recommended [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8385), but it didn't help. Any ideas? I am running `Anaconda3` environment.

Comment: According to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7529, it could be that cuDNN is not properly installed. Are you sure it is in your PATH variable?

Comment: yes it is there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On Windows, running "import tensorflow" generates No module named "\_pywrap\_tensorflow" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526626/issues-running-tensorflow#comment76047812_44526626

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that `tensorflow` on `windows` requires `python 3.5` or higher while my python was `2.7.8`. I found out that this was the problem by the help of this great [script](http://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c) which helps trace the source error and gives clear error messages.