# Error importing tensorflow Python 3.6.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I get this error whenever I try to import tensorFlow.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(**file**)])
  File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 54, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 60, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(**file**)])
  File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 54, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On Windows, running "import tensorflow" generates No module named "\_pywrap\_tensorflow" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526626/issues-running-tensorflow#comment76047812_44526626

Comment: its not a duplicate

Comment: Fixed it, I had the wrong Python version installed...