# installing Tensorflow with pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I have installed tensorflow with pip

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

Then when I'm in python and I try to

```
import tensorflow
```

I get [this](https://i.gyazo.com/0a66a7ceef62a8de55a4d59c58e57388.png) error.
https://i.gyazo.com/0a66a7ceef62a8de55a4d59c58e57388.png

I have the latest version of python and windows 10 x64

Comment: you need to share more information, have you set up your CUDA HOME path correctly? I found this guide useful to me for installing tesnorflow GPU on windows: https://nitishmutha.github.io/tensorflow/2017/01/22/TensorFlow-with-gpu-for-windows.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On Windows, running "import tensorflow" generates No module named "\_pywrap\_tensorflow" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526626/issues-running-tensorflow#comment76047812_44526626

Answer (score 0):

The errors that you got in the screenshot start with DLL Load failed - and I notice that you installed with pip3 and that you installed on windows installing for GPU use. [This guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) starts with a prerequisites that you may have ignored:

> Installing TensorFlow on Windows
>
> This guide explains how to install TensorFlow on Windows.
>
> Determine which TensorFlow to install
>
> You must choose one of the following types of TensorFlow to install:
>
> TensorFlow with CPU support only. **If your system does not have a
>   NVIDIA® GPU, you must install this version.** Note that this version of
>   TensorFlow is typically much easier to install (typically, in 5 or 10
>   minutes), so even if you have an NVIDIA GPU, ***we recommend installing
>   this version first.***
>
> TensorFlow with GPU support. TensorFlow programs
>   typically run significantly faster on a GPU than on a CPU. Therefore,
>   if your system has a NVIDIA® GPU meeting the prerequisites shown below
>   and you need to run performance-critical applications, you should
>   ultimately install this version.
>
> Requirements to run TensorFlow with GPU support
>
> If you are installing TensorFlow with GPU support using one of the
>   mechanisms described in this guide, then the following NVIDIA software
>   must be installed on your system:
>
> **CUDA® Toolkit 8.0.** For details, see NVIDIA's documentation **Ensure that
>   you append the relevant Cuda pathnames to the %PATH% environment**
>   variable as described in the NVIDIA documentation. The NVIDIA drivers
>   associated with CUDA Toolkit 8.0. cuDNN v5.1. For details, see
>   NVIDIA's documentation. Note that cuDNN is typically installed in a
>   different location from the other CUDA DLLs. **Ensure that you add the
>   directory where you installed the cuDNN DLL to your %PATH% environment
>   variable**. GPU card with CUDA Compute Capability 3.0 or higher. See
>   NVIDIA documentation for a list of supported GPU cards. If you have an
>   earlier version of the preceding packages, please upgrade to the
>   specified versions.

*The above from the linked page but with my highlighting added, (and other styling lost).*

You also need to ensure that you have a compatible graphics card fitted to the machine. If you are in any doubt try:

```
pip3 install --upgrade  tensorflow
```

You will get the CPU based version of tensorflow which does not require external software be installed & on the path but will run slower.