# error while executing 'import tensorflow as tf'

Tags: windows, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am just getting started with python/tensorflow.
Using [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) link to get started.
I have I have successfully installed tensor-flow, at least from the log it seems like that. My issue is when I try to import tenser-flow I am getting the following error.

```
>>>import tensorflow as tf
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper

    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__in
it__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper

    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__in
it__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper

    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__in
it__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper

    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__in
it__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_probl
ems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

### OS : Windows 8.1 , python version : 3.5.2

I have python 2.7,3.6,3.5 in my machine, but 3.5 is set as default.

Comment: have you went to the link the error provided you with? It has an explanation how to fix your problem. Have you tried to read what is written there?

Comment: Yes you are correct. My mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am putting this answer just for tensor-flow beginners. 
If you occur with above issue, what fixed my issue is

1. Put the installation of python 3.5(which is supported), install it in C:\ or any other locations other than the default.
2. download msvcp140.dll and place it in System32 and SysWOW64. I sued the following link to download [msvcp140.dll](https://www.dllme.com/dll/download/29970/msvcp140.dll).

Whole credit of this belongs to
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44466083/432216