# Installing tensorflow-gpu 1.3.0 on windows 10

Tags: tensorflow

I have been trying to install tensorflow-gpu on windows 10, via

pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu

When I do this I break the current installation of ordinary tensorflow!, and get this error: [On Windows, running "import tensorflow" generates No module named "_pywrap_tensorflow" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso).

Somehow I manage to fix this by re-installing ordinary tensorflow, but then when I import tensorflow in python 3.5.2 and try to identify my GPU, No device is found!

I have a Cuda 9.0 installed alongside cudnn64_6 defined as a DLL in CUDA/v9.0/bin, and I can run the nbody test program without problems and I can see the GPU being used for that demo application.

Is there any known issue with tensorflow-gpu 1.3.0?

Really struggling on this. Why does it have to be so problematic installing this library!

Please help
mg

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow 1.3 (and 1.4) require CUDA 8.0 and do not support later versions. You will either need to downgrade CUDA to 8.0 or make a custom build from source.