# No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am getting the error below when trying to install tensorflow for python in pip3 on Windows 10 Home.  I will try installing via Anaconda next but does anyone know if tensorflow will work with python 3.6.4?  (My system is pretty old.)

Error:
 ***"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )  No matching distribution found for tensorflow"***

The command I am using is:
***pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow***

Currently I have python version 3.6.4

Other Info:
Windows 10 Home
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
Processor: AMT Phenom(tm) Quad-Core Processor 2.4GHz

Comment: Installing TF on Windows tends to be messy...have you tried: `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow `?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply.  Looks like that's a no go.  I read on another thread not to try it unless you are using Python 3.5.3-amd64 and that newer versions would probably not install right.  The [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070) was regarding the GPU version though and was a bit older so I'm not sure if it still applies.  I'll keep trying and post progress if any is made.

Comment: Ok, I'm good to go.  I installed using the information from the [install page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) under the "Installing with Anaconda" section. (worked like a charm)

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading from python 32 bits to Python 3.4, 3.5 or 3.6 (64 bits) worked for me.

How to check if your installed Python is 64 bits:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41084963/3212785

Answer (score 3):

For those passing by and having the same error you may need to:

- downgrade/upgrade python version so that it fits in the supported interval - from what I've read tensorflow usually supports the latest version available on ubuntu and a bit before which is right now one version lower (3.5-3.8 instead of 3.9)
- upgrade python to a 64bit version

Hope this helped, downgrading worked for me

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/install

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, later figured out it has to do something with pip3 version.

Try running:

To upgrade pip3 version

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Then try:

```
pip3 install tensorflow==2.2
```

It's upon you which version of tensorflow you want to install