# How to install tensorflow in python 3.6 in win 7 32 bit

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow in system but I get the following error. If there is any way to install it in 32 bit python than please let me know.
Here is the error:

```
ERROR: Could not f
ind a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from
versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Comment: I think the only way to do it is to use 64 bit python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48390095/no-matching-distribution-found-for-tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, TensorFlow is not available for Windows 32-bit systems.

You can install TensorFlow only for 64-bit Windows systems.

However, it is possible to install it from source code.You can compile and install it in 32 bits linux systems or you can just update python 32 bits to Python 3.4, 3.5 or 3.6 (64 bits) and try that if it works.