# CPU Version of Tensorflow 1.7 and DLL Issues

Tags: tensorflow

Succesfully installed Tensorflow; but, getting following error message when importing tensorflow into Python (Jupyter Notebook).  This is on a Win 10 virtual.

Not using CUDA, and installed CPU version:  tensorflow-1.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

We also have the %PATH% set up appropriately for the following:
     [MS Visual C++ Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIikH.png)

```
`(base) C:\Temp\stack-package>python -c "import 
tensorflow;print(tensorflow._version_)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-    packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in     swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in     _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization     routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-    packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-    packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-    packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in     swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in     <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-    packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in     swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization     routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-    packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in     swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
```

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.`

Comment: If you didn't find a solution try this! https://stackoverflow.com/a/49792306/5212057