# Tensorflow in Windows installation error: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

Tags: python, tensorflow

after watching few videos on Youtube I though Tensorflow is such a cool kit. Having just a tiny bit of experience with Python, naturally I tried to install it get my hands dirty. Usually when I try to install some add-on for Python I just simply do:
    python -m pip install

(by the way I'm running Win10 on a laptop with i5-8250U & GeForce MX150)
but this method gives me no luck with Tensorflow. I then followed suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip), only changing

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

to

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.11.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

and it magically installed. But now when I try

```
import tensorflow
```

I get these nasty errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\Mee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Mee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Mee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Mee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Mee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Mee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\Mee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Mee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Mee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Would anyone who experienced similar error when importing tf for the first time give me a hand? Much appreciated.

Update: thanks to all who commented, problem solved! I just had to downgrade from Python 3.7 to 3.6. It's all works fine now.

Comment: What cpu are you running?

Comment: Intel Core i5 Gen 8

Comment: Oh ok. I had the same error, but it turns out that the problem was that my outdated intel core duo, was lacking avx instructions.

Comment: I doubt that this is the cause in your case

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/a/43566341/8625593?

Comment: Interesting, so this could also be caused by hardware? That seems strange

Comment: Apparently tensorflow is built requiring the AVX instruction set, which is something that is hardcoded into your cpu. However, for my case I had to install a version of tensorflow that did not use avx instructions

Comment: Yes, I've looked up the post you mentioned already. It looks quite involved; I assumed there must be a more elegant solution to this :(

Comment: I see, does that mean you have to go back using an older version?

Comment: If you want to try what worked for me I wrote an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50050336/8625593

Comment: And no, there is another user maintain a tensorflow version which is does not required avx instructions

Comment: Please follow the installation instructions carefully. TF does not work with python 3.7 yet.

Comment: I had the problem with the AVX instructions with an old Core i7 CPU, although I can't tell what gen. I think the latest version without AVX is v15.0 or v1.5.1, if you want to try that (see [v1.6.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/v1.6.0) release notes).

Comment: Wait that URL is for Mac, isn't it? That wouldn't work on Win10.

Comment: Look in [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) to find the correct package URL for your environment.

Comment: Thanks everyone, problem solved. I downgraded to Python 3.6 and everything works.