# Does tensorflow support Python 3.6.4 on Windows?

Tags: tensorflow, pip, python-3.6

I'm running a Windows computer with just a CPU (no GPU). When I run `pip install tensorflow -vvv` in order to see what pip is doing, it lists a lot of links, but for all of them, it says "Skipping link ... it is not compatible with this Python."

Does tensorflow support Python 3.6.4 on Windows? If so, what binary URL should I use to install it?

(I previously installed with [this version](http://--upgrade%20https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl) due to reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42596864), but ran into [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso) without the `DLL load failed` message, so I'm wondering if there's a better version I should use.)

Also, I'm aware that Tensorflow *says* [they support Python 3.x](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows), but right now it hasn't been working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably installed Python 32bits, you need the 64bits version

Comment: You can check which type of Python you are running by opening the interpreter and typing `import struct;print(struct.calcsize("P") * 8)`  (And thank you @f4. for responding, I had seen [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41084963/5049813), but misread it as being a wrong version of Tensorflow, not Python itself.)