# Python - Tensorflow won't import due to missing DLL's

Tags: python, tensorflow

## Problem

- Tensorflow will not import due to tensorflow.python.**pywrap_tensorflow_internal** not existing. I am recieving the following error '**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found**.'.

### Solution Attempts

- I have been attempting to follow a similar issue that was reported to the [Tensorflow documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22512). However, I cannot find the solution or any appropriate pointers in amongst the thread.
- I downloaded the MSVCP140.DLL file after reading on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso). However, I have not changed my System Path to suit as I am unsure what it should b changed too ***(This could be the issue)***.
- I have tried installing Tensorflow accross numerous Python versions (3.5.2, 3.6.0, 3.7.0) and the same error continues to occur.

### Question

- I am wondering can I use Tensorflow on this machine? and if so then what are the steps that I need to follow to configure Tensorflow to the correct settings.

## Set-up Environment

- Python version - 3.5.2
- Device - ThinkPad X1 Carbon, i7-8550U, 16GB, 256GB SSD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads). This is according to TensorFlow's [installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements).

Related to [tensorflow/tensorflow#35749](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35749#issuecomment-573313402).